# python - how to check if matrix is sparse or not

Tags: python, class, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix and I want to check if it is sparse or not.

Things I have tried:

1. isinstance method:

   ```
   if isinstance(<matrix>, scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix):
   ```

This works fine if I know exactly which sparse class I want to check.

2. getformat method: But it assumes that my matrix is sparse and give format

But I want a way to know if matrix is sparse or not, and should work irrespective of which sparse class.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
scipy.sparse.issparse(my_matrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do sparsity = 1.0 - count_nonzero(X) / X.size

This works for any matrices.